# Wikipedia's equivalent definitions of finite separable field extensions

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, definition

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separable_extension#Separable_elements_and_separable_extensions), given a finite field extension $E\supseteq F$, the following are equivalent:

1. $E$ is separable over $F$ i.e. for any $\alpha\in E$ the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $F$ is separable.
2. $E=F(a_1,\ldots,a_r)$ where $a_1,\ldots,a_r$ are separable elements of $E$.
3. $E=F(a)$ where $a$ is a separable element of $E$.
4. If $K$ is an algebraic closure of $F$, then there are exactly $[E:F]$ field homomorphisms of $E$ into $K$ which fix $F$.
5. If $K$ is a normal extension of $F$ containing $E$, then there are precisely $[E:F]$ field homomorphisms of $E$ into $K$ which fix $F$.

The first three definitions are equivalent by the Primitive Element Theorem, and naturally $5\implies 4$. However, I fail to see how $4$ and $5$ are equivalent to $1, 2, 3$ (even when thinking of the Fundamental Theorem of Galois Theory).

---

**Why are definitions 4 and 5 above equivalent to the rest?**

It would be sufficient to show $4$ implies either $1$,$2$, or $3$.

Comment: It's because the Galois group acts transitively on roots of an irreducible polynomial. Say $E=F(a_1)$, $[E:F]=r$. The minimal polynomial of $a_1$ (over $F$) has degree $r$. Let $a_1,\dots,a_r$ be its $r$ distinct roots in an algebraic closure. Then for each $i=1,\dots,r$ there is a unique field homomorphism of $E/F$ into an algebraic closure sending $a_1$ to $a_i$. This field homomorphism extends to an automorphism/permutation of $a_1,\dots,a_r$ in a normal extension of $E$.

Comment: @JohnDoe oh right, although as far as I can see this only shows that $1,2,3\implies 5$.

Comment: You already noted that $5\rightarrow 4$.  If you're asking why $4\rightarrow 5$ - it's because any field homomorphism of $E/F$ into an algebraic closure must map $a_1$ to one of the other $a_i$ which are the roots of the minimal polynomial of $a_1$, so it maps into a splitting field of this polynomial - and the splitting field is a subfield of any normal extension of $E$.

Comment: @JohnDoe I'm struggling to see how that shows that $4\implies 5$. I would see how that shows five if, for example, we had $E=F(a)$, yet that presupposes what we are trying to show.

Comment: $4\rightarrow 5$ because any field homomorphism of $E/F$ into an algebraic closure maps a root in $E$ of an irreducible polynomial with coefficients in $F$ to another root of same polynomial - and these other roots are in any normal extension of $E$.  It doesn't have to be a separable generator of $E/F$.  I'm not sure how to show that either $4$ or $5$ imply one of the first three - but I think it's probably best to show either 1 or 2, and not directly make the effort to show that there's a separable generator.