# Why is a field extension $L:K$ normal if and only if $\text{Aut}(L:K)$ acts transitively on the set of homomorphisms $L\to \overline{K}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, definition

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_extension#Equivalent_conditions_for_normality), given the algebraic extension $L:K$, the following are equivalent:

$a)$ The minimal polynomial over $K$ of every element in $L$ splits in $L$.

$b)$ $\text{Aut}(L:K)$ acts transitively on the set of homomorphisms $L\to \overline{K}$ where $\overline{K}$ is the algebraic closure of $K$.

I have found nothing similar to the above result (equivalence of the conditions) in Stewart's *Galois Theory*, and thus I'm wondering **why are the conditions above equivalent?**

Comment: There is an important condition on the homomorphisms you'll consider in b)

Comment: You mean the set of homomorphism $L\to\overline{K}$ over $K$ I guess, not just field homomorphisms. Well, each such homomorphism sends an element $x\in L$ to a root of its minimal polynomial, which is in $L$...

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4681686/wikipedias-equivalent-definitions-of-finite-separable-field-extensions) for context. It is probably better not to post each time an equivalence from wikipedia, but to have a look at a book on field theory.